# busco que en dos dias la funcion DISABLED aplique un boton

Tags: php, javascript, funciones, botón

tengo una consulta la cual es que trato que un boton input se desabilite en dos dias ya que tengo un formulario el cual me permite solicitar permisos a los jefes para faltar o para evitar venir el problema es que necesito que a los dos dias necesito que ya no se habilite comparto los archivos del update
ya sea que se desabilite el boton Actualizar o todos los inputs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
aqui iria el tiempo
</script>


<div style="background-color:transparent ;"><br>
        <h3 style="  color:white  ;">Editar usuario</h3>
    <center>    <form action="update.php" method="post" >
            <label for="comentarios" style="color:#1BB9B7;background-color:blue; font-size:20px; ">Razon: </label><br />
            <input style=" border:0px;border-radius:10px; background-color:blue ; color:white;" size="60" maxlength="40" type="text" name="comentarios" value="<?php if(isset($comentarios)) echo $comentarios; ?>"  /><br /><br />

            <label for="fecha_peticion" style="color:#1BB9B7  ;background-color:blue; font-size:20px;">fecha peticion: </label><br />
            <input style=" border:0px;border-radius:10px; background-color:blue ; color:white;" type="datatime-local" name="fecha_peticion" title="Recurda que la fecha va aaaa/mm/dd " value="<?php if(isset($fecha_peticion)) echo $fecha_peticion; ?>" /><br /><br />

            <label  for="nuv_labor" style="color:#1BB9B7  ;background-color:blue; font-size:20px;">Regresas a laborar: </label><br />

        <select name="nuv_labor" style=" border:0px;border-radius:10px; background-color:blue ; color:white;" >
    <option name="nuv_labor" value="<?php if(isset($nuv_labor)) echo $nuv_labor; ?>" ><?php if(isset($nuv_labor)) echo $nuv_labor; ?></option>


    <option value="Si" <?php if(!$nuv_labor=="En Revision"){echo"selected";}?>>Si</option>
    <option value="No" <?php if(!$nuv_labor=="Autorizado"){echo"selected";}?>>No</option>


    </select><br><br>

<body>

            <input class="btn-success" type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Actualizar" id="boton"  style=" border:0px;border-radius:10px; "  /><br /><br />
            <a class="btn" href="permisos.php" style=" border:0px;border-radius:10px; background-color:blue ; color:white;"><< Volver</a>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if(isset($id)) echo $id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sw" value="1" />
        </form></center>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te falta proporcionar más información. Se va a desactivar el botón 2 días, pero ¿Cuáles son las condiciones para desactivarlo? Supongo que por usuario y alguna fecha específica que hay que saber de dónde viene.

Comment: por una fecha la de local osea una vez el input se genere tengo en mi base de datos una columna la cual se define en tiempo que se da el insert con el NOW() desde hay quiero que pasando dos dias se bloque el boton y no se pueda actualizar la informacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, es simple solo debes agregar un condicional if con la fecha en la que quieres que se deshabilite este boton debes agregar este código en la etiqueta input de tu botón:

```
<?echo(date("Y-m-d") > "2020-04-17") ? "disabled" : "" ?>
```

Allí le dices que si la fecha de hoy es mayor a 2020-04-17 te de un disabled, y si no quedaria el botón habilitado, allí colocas la fecha que necesites o si quieres que sea a partir de x dia cambias el > por >=.

Comment: y se puede usar mi tabla la cual tiene la fecha ?? por ejemplo
<?echo(date("Y-m-d") > "fecha_registro") ? "disabled" : "" ?>

Comment: Si claro solo debes reemplazar la fecha que coloque "2020-04-17" por la fecha que tienes un tu tabla, quedaría <?echo(date("Y-m-d") > $fecha_registro) ? "disabled" : "" ?> siendo $fecha_registro la variable que viene de tu base de datos con la fecha y si el formato de tu fecha no es Y-m-d (Debe ser el mismo formato), puedes cambiar el date("Y-m-d") por el formato que tengas en tu tabla, ya sea "d-m-Y", o "Y-m-d H.i:s", espero así me entiendas mejor, Saludos!!

Comment: y para agregarlo al boton editar le pongo algun name o id

Comment: Si quieres la misma condición en el de editar también solo copia el <??> y pegalo donde lo necesites

Comment: lo agrege asi 

 <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>"  class='btn btn-success' ><?echo(date("Y-m-d") > $fecha_regis) ? "disabled" : "" ?>Editar</a>

Comment: Amigo, las etiquetas <a> no les funciona el disabled solamente a las <buttom> y a los <input>, asi que te recomiento cambies el <a> por un <buttom> para que te funcione el disabled, y las etiquetas <??> deben estar dentro de la propiedad en el caso de que sea un buttom debe quedar <buttom <??> > y no como lo colocaste en el <a> que colocaste <a><??>, espero me eniendas, Saludos!!

Comment: jeje lo intente poner pero me muestra el resultado de las fechas que agrege




<button type="submit"> <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>"  class='btn btn-success' ><?echo(date("Y-m-d") > $fecha_regis) ? "disabled" : "" ?>Editar</a> </button><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>" class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</a>